# How is burden measured?

Tags: transformer

How is burden measured for the secondary circuit of either a current transformer or potential transformer? Also, is there a test set made for measuring burden?

Comment: What is "burden"?

Comment: Do you mean burden voltage? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter#Burden_voltage

Comment: I suspect he means "load" but without knowing "load current" or "load impedance", that's no help.

Answer (score 1):

The [burden voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter#Burden_voltage) of a current meter isn't necessarily measured. A current meter essentially measures the voltage buildup due to a current through a known resistor. It is the voltage drop over the multimeter when measuring current.

The (shunt) resistor in the current meter is a know and static value, so if you know what current flows through it, you can calculate the burden voltage by applying [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)

The burden voltage in that case is \$U_{burden} = I_{measured} × R_{shunt}\$

Comment: This was mentioned in an EEVBlog video and I didn't get it. Now I understand it, +1.